# c++, manipulating the pointer to the first element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, element

I've written a small code to quickly explain my question:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    { int a [10] = { 200, 60, 100, 70, 0, 0, 105, 400, 450, 30};
      int *b = &a[0];
      int *c = &a[9];
      int *d = b+9;

      cout<<&b[9]<<endl
      <<c<<endl
      <<d<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

I don't understand why I had to use the address-of operator to get the same result. More specifically, shouldn't `b[9]` (and not `&b[9]`) be equal to `&a[9]` and `b+9`? I'm confused since as b is already defined as a pointer, b[9] should also be one, and it made sense to me for it to point to the same address as `b+9`.

And in my example, what does `b[9]` actually represent?

Comment: b[9] points to a[9]. b points to a[0], as does b[0]. When  you put a subscript on a pointer, the the subscript is added to the pointer. When you load a pointer, that's when you use the address-of operator. (Just to confuse things still further, int *0[b] also points to a[0].)

Comment: @PeteWilson: b[9] doesn't really _point_ to anything, in the sense that a pointer points to things.

Answer (score 2):

- b is int*
- b+9 is int*
- *(b+9) is int
- b[9] is int (the same as above)
- &b[9] is int*
- *(&b[9]) is int

Comment: How can b[9] be int &b[9]? If you replace it in the above script, b[9] and &b[9] are two different things. And what's confusing is that it is &b[9] what points to the last element of the original array a, not b[9].

Comment: b[9] is int, &b[9] is int*; p[i] the same as *(p+i)

Answer (score 2):

`b[9]` is, by definition, `*(b+9)`. That is, the array operator `[]` sums the index and the pointer, and then *dereferences that pointer*.

So:

```
b[9] == a[9]
b+9 ==  &(a[9])
```

are both true statements.

Comment: that's what I missed. Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 1):

`b[9]` is the last element of your array.

`&b[9]` is a pointer to this element.

`b + 9` is equivalent to the `&b[9]` form.

Answer (score 1):

The array subscript operator includes a dereference, which is why you need to use the address-of operator to get a pointer again.

`b[9]` is the same as `*(b+9)` by definition.